# Why selenium webdriver recognizes the <ins> instead of the input box itself?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Python. On the a webpage, I have an input checkbox :

```
<input class=“theme1" type="checkbox" value="1" name=“sale_enabled">
<ins class=“theme-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
```

When I do:

```
driver.find_element_by_name(‘sale_enabled’).click()
```

Selenium webdriver cannot find the checkbox and check it.

but if I do:

```
driver.find_element_by_class(‘theme1-helper’).click()
```

then Selenium was able to find it.

Why is that?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing tag on your input element. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: You either have class  `theme1` or `theme-helper`. In your second line of code, the class name does not match the html.

Comment: @jzarob Input elements don't need a close tag.  looks like you have an ascii quote in the input tag right after class=, change that to a regular quote.

Answer (score 2):

Your selenium selectors look correct (though the class `theme1-helper` doesn't exist in your html).

Looks like your problem might be your HTML using a strange character, causing it to parse incorrectly.

```
<input class=“theme1" type="checkbox" value="1" name=“sale_enabled">
             ^ this character should be "            ^ and so should this one
<ins class=“theme-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
```

So, looks like some issue with the name attribute not being accessible as a result:

```
<input class="theme1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="sale_enabled">
<ins class=“theme-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
```